# You likely forgot to export your component from the file in

Tags: react-native

i have this error last days and still couldnt find the solution.[error code ise here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rc4MY.png)

Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built in components) or class/function (for composite components) but got: undenifed.You likely forgot to export your component from the file its defined in, or you might have mixed up default or named imports.

Check the render of method of 'cellRenderer'

i updated React for last version. but still error is continue.NPM versiyon ise 6.13.1. i think error is very small but i cant see it.thanks for your helps.

here is my codes;

dataItem.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Body, Button, Left, ListItem, Right, Text, Thumbnail} from 'native-base';



class DataItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.data = props.data;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ListItem thumbnail>
        <Left>
          <Thumbnail
            square
            source={{
              uri:
                this.data.urlToImage != null
                  ? this.data.urlToImage
                  : 'data:image/png;base64,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',
            }}
          />
        </Left>
        <Body>
          <Text numberOfLines={2}>{this.data.title}</Text>
          <Text note numberOfLines={2}>
            {this.data.description}
          </Text>
        </Body>
        <Right>
          <Button transparent>
            <Text>OKU</Text>
          </Button>
        </Right>
      </ListItem>
    );
  }
}
export default DataItem ;
```

tab1.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Alert, View, ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native';
import { Container, Content, List, Text } from 'native-base';

import {DataItem} from '../../component/dataItem';

import {getArticles} from '../../service/news';

export default class ListThumbnailExample extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state= {
            isLoading: true,
            data: null
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        getArticles().then(data => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoading: false,
                    data: data
                });
            }
        )
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.data);
        let view = this.state.isLoading ? (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <ActivityIndicator animating={this.state.isLoading} color="#00f0ff" />
                <Text style={{marginTop: 10}} children="Please Wait.." />
            </View>
        ) : (
            <List
                dataArray={this.state.data}
                renderRow={(item) => {
                    return (
                        <DataItem onPress={this.handleItemDataOnPress} data={item} />
                    )
                }} />
        )


        return (
            <Container>
                <Content>
                    <List
                       dataArray={this.state.data}
                       renderRow={(item) => {
                           return <DataItem data={item}/>
                    }}
                    />
                </Content>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? You get an error message, have you used it to investigate?

Comment: remove the curly braces in your import `import DataItem from '../../component/dataItem';`

Comment: i really thank you azium. it works!!